# Scikit-Learn cross validation function not allowing custom folds when indices are not sequential

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Attempting to pass in custom cross validation folds to sklearn's cross validate function.

The cross validate function seems to be triggering an error because it's insisting on using position-based indexing, rather than label-based indexing. The indices I'm passing in my cv_folds argument are consistent with the original dataframe's indices. The reason this is relevant is because I want to use a hash function value to select subsets for my train-test split, as well as my cv folds. I get the following error: IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8, 3), columns=['feature_1', 'feature_2', 'feature_3'])
```

```
train_index_list = [0,1,2,5,6,7]
test_index_list = [3,4]
X_train = df2.loc[train_index_list].drop(columns='feature_3').copy()
y_train = df2.loc[train_index_list]['feature_3'].copy()
```

```
# 2-fold cross validation
cv_folds = [ ([0,1,2,],[5,6,7]), ([5,6,7], [0,1,2])]
```

```
cv_output = cross_validate(model, X_train, y_train,  scoring=['neg_mean_squared_error'], cv=cv_folds)
```

This triggers an error. But what puzzles me is that the following lines run just fine

```
X_train.loc[train_index_list]
y_train.loc[train_index_list]
```

How do I resolve this so I can pass in my custom-defined cv folds into Scikit-Learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a workaround by using a `Index.get_indexer` to convert labels to index positions:

```
def cv_folds(df, labels):
    for i, j in labels:
        i = df.index.get_indexer(i)
        j = df.index.get_indexer(j)
        yield (i.tolist(), j.tolist())

labels = [([0, 1, 2], [5, 6, 7]), ([5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2])]
cv = cv_folds(X_train, labels)
cv_output = cross_validate(model, X_train, y_train, cv=cv,
                           scoring=['neg_mean_squared_error'])
```

Test:

```
>>> list(cv_folds(X_train, labels))
    [([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]), ([3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2])]  # <- positions
#   [([0, 1, 2], [5, 6, 7]), ([5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2])]  # <- labels
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. I'll also add that using SKLearn's GroupKFold and creating a label column worked for my use case. But this is the best solution